# Flutter web app not changes in release mode

Tags: flutter, github-pages

I make flutter web app and test in debug mode. That is working. Later, Run `flutter build web --release` this command and then copy files from `build/web` to the web folder and host on github pages. All is work.

later, I fix some functions and do that above steps again, but nothing changes in github pages. Always show old web, functions. But there is changes in web debug mode. I build with flutter 2.0. How to fix that problem or how should I do?

Comment: Try in incognito

Comment: I am not clear, what you mean, how to related with incognito mode?

Comment: You are probably viewing the cache files in browser. Check from an incognito window to see if the changes are reflected

Comment: No, I test from my Phone browser. But nothing changes. Always show old website, although an icon was not changed.

Comment: You can still have cache in phone browser. Please open an incognito window from your phone browser and check once

Comment: I test with changing with the new git repo but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve now...

**1.**
Clean the build file or type the command `flutter clean`

**2.**
Build web release with `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release`

**3.**
Copy all of files and folder inside from web folder inside build folder `build/web` , to the repo and push again.

Answer (score 0):

Do flutter clean. Build for web again and upload the latest build files. Probably your ide created a build from cache

Comment: I manually delete build file, ```flutter clean```, build again with ```flutter build web --release``` and copy to github pages repo local folder and do commit, in here git say nothing was changes. Really I change may changes but why this happen.

Comment: Check your gitignore if it's ignoring files that you changed

Comment: No.. for this bug, I don't add gitignore file in that repo that use for github pages.

Comment: Try creating a new branch and pushing all your files in it